# Error "StreamModeError: Fasta files must be opened in text mode" in BioPython on a Streamlit App

Tags: biopython, streamlit

Please Assist, How can I resolve this Error?

I am building a streamlit app that take uploaded FASTA Files as input and read them.

I am getting the error below when I try to read an uploaded fasta file on my streamlit app

**THE ERROR:**

**StreamModeError: Fasta files must be opened in text mode.**

**Traceback:**

```
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 475, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\PycharmProjects\SARS_CoV_2_Mutation_Forecasting_GUI\SARS_CoV_2_Mutation_Forecasting_GUI.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\PycharmProjects\SARS_CoV_2_Mutation_Forecasting_GUI\SARS_CoV_2_Mutation_Forecasting_GUI.py", line 21, in main
    protein_sample = SeqIO.read(seq_file, 'fasta')
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\__init__.py", line 652, in read
    iterator = parse(handle, format, alphabet)
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\__init__.py", line 605, in parse
    return iterator_generator(handle)
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\FastaIO.py", line 183, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, mode="t", fmt="Fasta")
File "C:\Users\Sir Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqIO\Interfaces.py", line 53, in __init__
    raise StreamModeError(
```

**THE CODE GIVING THE ERROR**

```
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
from Bio import SeqIO


def main():

    st.title('Covid-19 Mutation Forecasting App')

    menu = ['Forecast Mutation', 'About The App']
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select Activity', menu)

    if choice == 'Forecast Mutation':
        st.subheader('Mutation Forecasting Workspace')

        seq_file = st.file_uploader('Upload a Sequence File:', type=['fasta'])

        if seq_file is not None:

            protein_sample = SeqIO.read(seq_file, 'fasta')
            st.write(protein_sample)
            loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("")

            next_step = st.checkbox('Forecast')
            if next_step:

                states = None
                next_char = tfio.genome.read_fastaq(protein_sample)
                result = [next_char]

                for n in range(100):
                    next_char, states = one_step_reloaded.generate_one_step(next_char, states=states)
                    result.append(next_char)

                print(tf.strings.join(result)[0].numpy().decode("utf-8"))

    else:
        st.subheader('About The App')
        st.caption('Given the first few codons of a SARS-CoV-2 Spike Protein, '
                   'the App forecasts and display the complete sequence of the mutant')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you started:

```
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
from Bio import SeqIO
from io import StringIO


def main():

    st.title('Covid-19 Mutation Forecasting App')

    menu = ['Forecast Mutation', 'About The App']
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select Activity', menu)

    if choice == 'Forecast Mutation':
        st.subheader('Mutation Forecasting Workspace')

        seq_file = st.file_uploader('Upload a Sequence File:', type=['fasta'])

        if seq_file is not None:
            
            # To convert to a string based IO:
            stringio = StringIO(seq_file.getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
            for record in SeqIO.parse(stringio, 'fasta'):
                sequence = str(record.seq)
                st.write(f'Length of sequence: {len(sequence)}')

                # The unique characters in the FASTA file
                vocab = sorted(set(sequence))
                st.write(f"{len(vocab)} unique characters: {', '.join(vocab)}")

                tensor = tfio.genome.sequences_to_onehot(sequence)
                st.write(tensor)

    else:
        st.subheader('About The App')
        st.caption('Given the first few codons of a SARS-CoV-2 Spike Protein, '
                   'the App forecasts and display the complete sequence of the mutant')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

I used `tfio.genome.sequence_to_onehot` instead of `tfio.genome.read_fastaq`, because you are reading [a FASTA file, not a FASTQ file](https://compgenomr.github.io/book/fasta-and-fastq-formats.html).